# HTML: post and page number organization

Tags: html, post, indexing, blogs

I've started keeping a blog on my site, without the assistance of WordPress, Blogger, or any other external services.

If I want to keep no more than say .. five posts on a page .. what's the simplest way to go about indexing them? I mean, after fifteen posts, I'd have three pages, and if I wanted to put a link on each page that linked to next oldest collection of posts, I would need to constantly be updating the links as page 2 turns into page 3, then turns into page 4, etc., etc., etc.

For instance, this popular blog brainpickings has pages nicely indexed:
https://www.brainpickings.org/page/2/ , https://www.brainpickings.org/page/3/
.. and so on for 1,465 pages.

How might I painlessly index my own pages in the same manner?

Comment: This can't be done in plain HTML if that's what you're asking. You can either look into stuff like Jekyll or Middleman or build it yourself using PHP for instance.

Comment: I have some rudimentary knowledge of JavaScript; can that possibly be of use to me here? [Even better -- might there be a tutorial that you can point me to?] .. Thanks!

Comment: Certainly there are ways to do it with Javascript or jQuery. This is a possibility for instance: http://web.enavu.com/js/jquery/jpaginate-jquery-pagination-system-plugin/ (or google Javascript Pagination)

But I wouldn't recommend it on the long run. If I were you, just look into Jekyll, Middleman or something really basic such as https://cdmedia.github.io/cms.js/

Comment: Ah. Thank you very much for sharing this information with me.